# Alternating sum of binomials divided by a polynomial of the index

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I'm working with a sequence of $k$ by $k$ matrices $M^n$ whose entries satisfy

$$M^n_{ij} = \binom{j-1}{i-1} \sum_{l=0}^{j-i} \binom{j-i}{l} (-1)^{l} (\frac{1}{i+l})^n, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I've been trying without luck to simplify this sum, specifically

$$  \sum_{l=0}^{j-i} \binom{j-i}{l} (-1)^{l} (\frac{1}{i+l})^n $$

One avenue is to expand out the binomials in the denominator:

$$\sum_{l=0}^{j-i}\frac{\binom{j-i}{l} (-1)^l}{\sum_r^n \binom{n}{r}i^nl^{r-n}} $$

But I think this may be going backwards rather than forwards.

I also tried the strategy in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3369814/978915 of using generating functions, i.e.

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{l+i}\bigg)^n = n![x^n]\exp\big(\frac{x}{l+i}\big)$$

where $[]$ is the "coefficient of" operator. This leads to

$$\sum_{l=0}^{j-i} \binom{j-i}{l} (-1)^{l} \big(\frac{1}{i+l}\big)^n =  n![x^n] \sum_{l=0}^{j-i} \binom{j-i}{l} (-1)^{l} \exp\big(\frac{x}{l+i}\big) $$

$$= n![x^n] \sum_{l=0}^{j-i} \binom{j-i}{l} \exp(-\mathbf{i}\pi l) \exp\big(\frac{x}{l+i}\big) = n![x^n] \sum_{l=0}^{j-i} \binom{j-i}{l} \exp\big(\frac{\mathbf{i}\pi l(l+i) + x}{l+i}\big) $$

Unfortunately the $(-1)^l$ and the exponential can't be simplified in the same way as in that example.

There's also this interesting identity from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3657580/978915 , which does not cover this case because here $0 \leq \tau \leq k$

[image]